# I have run this many times but it showing that path is inncorrect

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

**Code Error**

```
train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory ('D:/Semesters/Final Year Project/Images--Datasets/'  target_size = image_shape,batch_size = 64,color_mode= 'grayscale')
test_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory ('D:/Semesters/Final Year Project/Images--Datasets/' target_size = image_shape,color_mode= 'grayscale',shuffle= False,batch_size = 64,class_mode = 'categorical')
```

**Output**

```
File "C:\Users\DELL\.spyder-py3\train.py", line 26
    train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory ('D:/Semesters/Final Year Project/Images--Datasets/'  target_size = image_shape,batch_size = 64,color_mode= 'grayscale')
                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a comma **after the path/before target_size**

it should be:

```
train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory ('D:/Semesters/Final Year Project/Images--Datasets/', target_size = image_shape, batch_size = 64, color_mode= 'grayscale')
test_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory ('D:/Semesters/Final Year Project/Images--Datasets/', target_size = image_shape,color_mode= 'grayscale',shuffle= False,batch_size = 64,class_mode = 'categorical')
```